# Android - Listview Items position decreasing

Tags: android, listview

I'm building an App that receives all wifi networks arround my house.

All wifi networks are being listed inside a Listview.

Now I would like to open a new activity when some listview item is clicked. But before that I would like to get the SSID from the selected Item.

I'm using onItemClick to get the position from the item and is working fine. The problem that I'm getting is that when I click at some item, I get a different SSID from the current selected item, the values are being desplayed like that:

```
WIFI 1 - When I click here I get the SSID from WIFI 3

WIFI 2 - When I click here I get the SSID from WIFI 2

WIFI 3 - When I click here I get the SSID from WIFI 1
```

Instead of getting the SSID from the wifi 1 when I click at wifi one and etc.

Can you guys check what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        lv.setClickable(true);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();


            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));       


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   test();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 8000);
                }
            };

        handler.postDelayed(refresh, 2000);   
    }



    private void test() {
    {

        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1; 
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("", "" + results.get(arg2).SSID);
                }

            });

            while (size >= 0) 
            {  
                LinkedHashMap<String, String> item = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); 

                String BSSID = results.get(size).BSSID;

                int frequency = results.get(size).frequency;

                if(!results.get(size).SSID.equals("FET")) { 

                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID.concat("")); 
                arraylist.add(item); 

                }

                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  


            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        { }         

    }    
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order in which you add your list items to `arraylist`

```
try 
{
    size = 0;
    ...
    while (size < results.size())
    {
      ...
      arraylist.add(item);
      ...
      size++;
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't receive any wifi SSID after doing that.